# Instructions on small car, came with Technic Race Car, circa 1986

Tags: technic, instructions

When I was about 10 (so, about 1986), I had a Technic race car (formula-1 like), and the instructions had an alternate thing you could make. It was just a small car, with rack and pinion steering.

I must have made it 100s of times, and would like to find the instructions again, to make it now. I don't have the race car kit, but I probably do have enough LEGO to make the smaller car.

I've tried to work out what the original kit was, but can't locate it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks, Brock

Comment: Any additional details you remember? Colour would definitely help, as well as an indication of the size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to browse the [list of Technic sets on Brickset](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/default.aspx?theme=Technic) (sort by year of release, ascending).

There aren't that many before 1990 so it should be easy to find, one which sounds a bit like what you describe is [8865 Test Car](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8865-1) from 1988.

Comment: I don't really remember any more details. I think it was mostly one color, red or black.

The Test Car linked above might be it. I can see it has a moveable seat, and I think I remember that. 

The three models linked all look like ones we (me and kids) could make with our existing stockpile.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

the two sets that come into my mind when reading the description are a [Go-Kart (8842)](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8842-1) and a [Roadster (8832)](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8832-1) - maybe it's one of those (would be a lot easier if you remember some additional details - the main color, for example).